# Coding Sylvester sequence

Tags: python, recursion, sylvester

I need to code the Sylvester sequence in Python. The formula for the sequence is defined as

```js
$$s_n = 1 + \prod_ {
  i = 0
} ^ {
  n - 1
}
s_i$$
```

Where `$s_0 = 2$`.

However, I am having too much trouble writing this code in Python. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to do it?

Comment: What seems to be the trouble?

Answer (score 2):

A simple recursive solution in Python:

```
def sylvelster(n):
    product = 1
    for k in range(n):
        product *= sylvelster(k)
    return product + 1
```

Or you could go for the always popular sophisticated looking one liner:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul

def sylvelster(n):
    return 1 + reduce(mul, map(sylvelster, range(n)), 1)
```

Or an iterative solution (with explicit stack) instead of a recursive one (with implicit stack):

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul

def sylvelster(n):
    products = [2]
    for k in range(n):
        products.append(1 + reduce(mul, products, 1))
    return products[-1]
```